# Python - os.system is placing an unwanted (and unnecessary) newline and a 0 at the end of output

Tags: python, os.system

I don't know why it's doing this and when I try to trim it it spits out an error.

```
>>> print os.system('uptime')
21:05  up  9:40, 2 users, load averages: 0.69 0.76 0.82
0
>>> print os.system('uptime')[:-2]
21:07  up  9:42, 2 users, load averages: 0.75 0.74 0.80
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Does anyone know how I can stop this from happening or how to remove it without an error? Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

`os.system` isn't doing any such thing; what is happening is that `uptime` itself is writing to stdout (real stdout, not Python's `sys.stdout`), and `os.system` is returning the return value of `uptime`, which is 0 (indicating it exited successfully).

If you want to access the string `uptime` prints to stdout within Python, you'll have to use some other way of calling it, like `subprocess.Popen`.

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> uptime = subprocess.Popen('uptime', stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> output = uptime.stdout.read()
>>> output
' 04:20:09 up 12:13,  5 users,  load average: 0.99, 1.15, 1.25\n'
```

See the [`subprocess` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) for more details.

Answer (score 3):

[**`os.system()`**](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system) first executes the command in a subshell. That subshell prints the first line that you see.

On Unix, the return value is the exit status of the process. That is the `0` that you see in the interpreter. You could suppress this by assigning it to a variable:

```
>>> x = os.system('uptime')
14:12  up 21:45, 4 users, load averages: 1.13 0.93 0.82
>>>
```

Alternatively, using [**`subprocess.call()`**](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#replacing-os-system):

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> status = subprocess.call('uptime')
14:19  up 21:52, 4 users, load averages: 1.12 0.93 0.86
>>> print status
0
```

Perhaps you'd rather capture both the output and the returned status in variables, so that you can manipulate these before displaying them (or not):

```
>>> pipe = subprocess.Popen(['uptime'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
>>> 
>>> for line in pipe.stdout:
...     print line
... 
14:36  up 22:10, 4 users, load averages: 0.59 0.59 0.65

>>> status = pipe.wait()
>>> 
>>> print status
0
```

Answer (score 2):

`os.system` does not return the contents of stdout. if you want to capture those use `os.popen("uptime").read()`

Comment: While that works, it should be noted `os.popen` has been [deprecated](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.popen) since Python 2.6.

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't have to print the output.

The actual command called by os.system prints to stdout and the function os.system() returns the return of the command as an integer.

So try

```
os.system('uptime')
```